# tinymce editing panel moves out of browser

Tags: css, tinymce

Tinymce, the editing panel moved out of the right window edge and few of the buttons are not accessible.

`http://awesomescreenshot.com/0344zlra39`

Check the image at the above link, you can see what I mean.

Thanks.

Comment: And where should it be displayed? In the comment box?

Comment: You know, example code in this instance may help you get more helpful responses.

Comment: sorry for the later reply, been busy with other stuffs. @cptstarling - it just need to display towards the left while the content are at the edge of the window. Actually you question is not relative.

Comment: @DarkHippo - example code not possible, you will be tracked out of my question if I send any.

Comment: All coders, this issue has not been solved yet, help appreciated.